# Using C# Count() with a function

Tags: c#, linq, max, predicate

I'm trying to figure out how many times the **maximum value** of an array occurs within the array by using Linq's[`.Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) with a predicate inside. However, I don't fully understand how to do it. From reading the MSDN's scant example I thought I understood, but apparently not!

This is what I thought of:

```
string[] test = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "4" };
string max = test.Max();
Label1.Text = test.Count(p => p == max);
```

But that did not work. So I tried changing **max** to an integer to see if that would work, but that did not work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What does it do, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the Where function to filter first then count:

```
Label1.Text = test.Where(p => p == max).Count().ToString();
```

Comment: You don't **need** filtering with `Where` first. `Count` has an overload that takes a `Func<T, bool>` predicate and only counts the matching items.

Comment: @Mehrdad: didn't know that, would use your answer then

Comment: `list.Count(item => item.Value == "something")` would be a better and easy way.

Answer (score 16):

Using [`Count(predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) is OK. You just need to convert the return value (which is an integer) to string.

```
Label1.Text = test.Count(p => p == max).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        int[] test = { 2, 45, 3, 23, 23, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 23, 45, 45, 45 };
        int count = test.Count(i => i == test.Max());
```

Now you have the count which is your final count. Makes more sense with an int collection. Now to display it, you can just call ToString() on count.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Label1.Text = test.Where(t => t == test.Max()).Count().ToString();
```